# I purchased E580 and can't get it to boot after installing windows 7

Tags: windows, boot, bsod, lenovo-laptop

My computer came with only DOS, so I installed windows 7 from bootable USB. The process went smooth until the 1st reboot after installation finished. It gets BSOD and is caught in a loop of resetting and again crashing. The error message is visible for a split second only. Here is image of error:

[image]

I then proceeded to try to install Windows 10 to see if this might be the reason for the error. To my surprise, the installer could not locate any drive to install Windows 10.

Hope I can get some advice what to try next. Could I be missing some critical software update?

Comment: Can you boot a rescue disk and do what the error message says:  run `CHKDSK /F`?

Comment: The E580 comes with Win10 pre-installed.  If your machine came with DOS and you had to try installing Win7, there's something missing in the details.  It sounds like you got someone else's defective machine that had been wiped.

Comment: https://www.notebookcheck.net/Microsoft-blocks-Windows-7-and-8-1-updates-for-Kaby-Lake-and-Ryzen-PCs.207276.0.html explains Microsoft blocks Windows 7 on some CPUs, Please look at the serial number plate on the bottom and find the Lenovo model number, something like *20KSS0MW00* then click on [edit] and add the model number to your original post. We alreas need the real model number, not the 'marketing Series' name like E580, as there are several different E580s with different CPUs; some seventh generation, some eighth generation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

In the BIOS, set the **SATA Controller Mode** to **AHCI**.

AHCI is an advanced host control interface that can play the potential acceleration function of SATA hard disk, especially solid state hard disk. It is more necessary to use AHCI hard disk mode. Open ahci generally enter the BIOS to set before installing the system.

1. Press F2 to enter the BIOS during startup;
2. In the BIOS, press the → arrow key to move to Configuration, select SATA Controller Mode, then press Enter, select AHCI, press Enter, and finally press F10 to save and restart.

[image]

3. View if we can boot into Win 7.